Amadeus "On-Demand Flight Status" API issue in negative time zone
I experience some problems when trying to receive flight status for flights in negative time zones.
For example here is a flight: carrierCode=OS, flightNumber=7910, scheduledDepartureDate=2024-08-28 (for test you can pick any future date, it's daily regular flight). It departs from Newark airport (EWR) at 23:00 (local time, EDT). However when it is 23:00 2024-08-28 in New Jersey, it is already 03:00 2024-08-29 (the "next" day) in GMT-0 time zone. As the result I can't use "On-Demand Flight Status" API to check flight status and the following error is returned:
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "code" : 4926,
    "title" : "INVALID DATA RECEIVED",
    "detail" : "Query parameter 'scheduledDepartureDate' should not be past date",
    "source" : {
      "parameter" : "scheduledDepartureDate",
      "example" : "2020-06-10"
    },
    "status" : 400
  } ]
}

Is this a bug, or is there a way to workaround this limitation?
Request example:
https://api.amadeus.com/v2/schedule/flights?carrierCode=OS&flightNumber=7910&scheduledDepartureDate=2024-10-20

What data are you sending to the API (, and to which API exactly) ?

@Luuk I've added link to the API and request example.

I posted a request to test.api.amadeus.com, and it provides an answer. So it is unclear how/why you are getting this.  Maybe contact amadeus? (Option below "post your question on stackoverflow on this page: https://developers.amadeus.com/support )

I've wrote to them like several months ago. Still nothing…

This is an issue with their API. The official response from Amadeus support states: This seems to be a limitation, as you cannot call the API using past dates. We have raised this to our technical team, we will keep you updated..

To the test system the request works:
The request was adapted from the provided URL in the question and using step 3 on the Getting Started page)
curl "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/schedule/flights?carrierCode=OS&flightNumber=7910&scheduledDepartureDate=2024-10-20" -H 'Authorization: Bearer ********'
{
  "meta" : {
    "count" : 1,
    "links" : {
      "self" : "https://test.api.amadeus.com/v2/schedule/flights?carrierCode=OS&flightNumber=7910&scheduledDepartureDate=2024-10-20"
    }
  },
  "data" : [ {
    "type" : "DatedFlight",
    "scheduledDepartureDate" : "2024-10-20",
    "flightDesignator" : {
      "carrierCode" : "OS",
      "flightNumber" : 7910
    },
    "flightPoints" : [ {
      "iataCode" : "EWR",
      "departure" : {
        "timings" : [ {
          "qualifier" : "STD",
          "value" : "2024-10-20T23:00-04:00"
        } ]
      }
    }, {
      "iataCode" : "LHR",
      "arrival" : {
        "timings" : [ {
          "qualifier" : "STA",
          "value" : "2024-10-21T11:10+01:00"
        } ]
      }
    } ],
    "segments" : [ {
      "boardPointIataCode" : "EWR",
      "offPointIataCode" : "LHR",
      "scheduledSegmentDuration" : "PT7H10M",
      "partnership" : {
        "operatingFlight" : {
          "carrierCode" : "UA"
        }
      }
    } ],
    "legs" : [ {
      "boardPointIataCode" : "EWR",
      "offPointIataCode" : "LHR",
      "aircraftEquipment" : {
        "aircraftType" : "763"
      },
      "scheduledLegDuration" : "PT7H10M"
    } ]
  } ]
}


You are correct that this API generally works fine. However, if you look closely at the question, you'll notice the issue arises when the API is used while it's still 'today' in some regions (e.g., New Jersey), but already 'yesterday' in the GMT-0 timezone.

Ok, now Only someone need to find a flight where these conditions apply. I was not able to find such a flight....

You can easily reproduce the issue with the flight I've mentioned carrierCode=OS, flightNumber=7910. You only need to request flight status close to the departure time.

I added some lines to a crontab, so it should run a couple of times later today (before and after departure of that flight). Now I need to find time to check the output of the script (some day.... )
